# Celery decorator

Tags: python, celery, decorator

I have a task that performs a bulk update. Also, this task sends the status of the task to a certain place, for example, the task has started and the task has been successfully completed. I want to wrap this action in a decorator so that I can use it in subsequent tasks. But I ran into a problem that I can't attach a decorator to a celery task.

```
@celery.task
def change_statuses(*args, **kwargs) -> None:
    call class which update status of task to pending
    making bulk update
    call class which update status of task to success
```

So I want to make like this decorator as base decorator

```
def update_state(state):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            call class{state} which update status of task to pending

            func(*args, **kwargs)

            call class{state} which update status of task to success

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

And call this decorator in every celery task, for example:

```
@celery.task
@update_state(UpdateBuildingsStatusEvent)
def change_status(*args, **kwargs) -> None:
    making bulk update
```

But i have error:

```
The full contents of the message body was:
'{"task": "tasks.buildings_changes_statuses.change_status", "name": "change_status", "id": "******", "args": [], "kwargs": {"building_ids": [1, 2], "macroservice_id": 1, "user_id": 1, "macroservice_status": "connect", "task_id": "***"}}' (314b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aidar/Work/services.background_tasks/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 581, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'tasks.buildings_changes_statuses.change_status'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue you have is that the `celery.task` decorator is no longer getting called on a function called `change_status` (which is referenced by name somewhere else). Instead it is getting applied to the return value of your decorator, named `wrapper`. Since that has a different name, the `celery` code doesn't know that it is standing in for `change_status`.

To work around this issue, you can probably use `functools.wraps` to update various attributes of your `wrapper` function to match the function it is wrapped around. Try this:

```
from functools import wraps

def update_state(state):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)                     # apply fuctools.wraps here
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            ...
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```